# How to persist notebooks from Dask Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, dask

I am running a Docker compose file (`docker-compose up --force-recreate`) to start Dask scheduler, workers, and the Dask Jupyter notebook. I have added volumes as follows:

```
  notebook:
    image: daskdev/dask-notebook
    depends_on:
      - scheduler
      - worker
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    environment:
      DASK_SCHEDULER_ADDRESS: "tcp://scheduler:8786"
    volumes:
      - "~/Personal/python-workspace/notebooks:/home/jovyan/work"
      - "~/Personal/docker-volumes/tmp:/tmp"
```

Whenever I try to create a file under the `work` folder, I get an HTTP `403` with the following logs in the terminal:

```
notebook_1   | [I 03:28:19.584 LabApp] Saving file at /Untitled.ipynb
notebook_1   | [I 03:28:35.668 LabApp] Creating new file in /work
notebook_1   | [W 03:28:35.670 LabApp] Permission denied: work/untitled.txt
```

How do I go about resolving this and persisting my notebooks?

Comment: what is the user inside container? is it allow to write on `/home/jovyan/work`?

Comment: @Adiii The user inside the container is `$NB_USER` (`jovyan`) when the Jupyter server is launched. More on that [here](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/common.html#docker-options).

Answer (score 0):

On the host (outside the docker container), this should work and allow you to avoid this **Denied error** :

`sudo chmod -R 777 ~/Personal/python-workspace/notebooks`

But that's not the correct way to fix the error and since `daskdev/dask-notebook`is based on `jupyter/base-notebook` you should refer to [this documentation](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/common.html) :

Refering to this URL, I think adding these environment variables in your docker-compose file should help fix your issue without having to use a command such as `chmod`:

- `CHOWN_HOME=yes`
- `CHOWN_HOME_OPTS='-R'`